# Is there a way to take token out from the contract?

Tags: token, blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, transfer

I created a contract and deposited some ERC20 tokens to there.
Is there a way to take to token out form the contract to my wallet?
I also want to know how to approve from the contract to other one wallet.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement a custom function in your contract that invokes the `transfer()` function of the token contract.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

interface IERC20 {
    function transfer(address to, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
}

contract MyContract {
    address owner = address(0x123);

    function withdrawToken(address tokenContract, uint256 amount) external {
        // send `amount` of tokens
        // from the balance of this contract
        // to the `owner` address
        IERC20(tokenContract).transfer(owner, amount);
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean when I already deployed the contract without that function

Comment: @Mr.Moon Then there's no way. You'd need to know the private key to your contract address, which is unknown and practically not possible to guess.